# python dbus how to get object value

Tags: python, dbus

```
import dbus

session_bus = dbus.SessionBus()
print(session_bus)

serviceName = "com.qcom.QCAT"
service = session_bus.get_object(
    serviceName, # Bus name
    "/Applications/QCAT/QCAT/bin/QCAT", # Object path
)

print(service)
appVersion = service.get_dbus_method('AppVersion')
print(appVersion)
```

---

I want to print appVersion at this code, but it actually print object _DeferreMethod object
How can I get the value of AppVersion.(arguemnts)
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VF3z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting information about the method in `appVersion`, rather than calling it and getting its return value. Try adding something like:

```
service_application = dbus.Interface(service, 'com.qcom.Application')
appVersion = service_application.AppVersion()
print(appVersion)
```